# How do we correctly dynamically allocate memory multiple times?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 20

int main() {

/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
int N, Q;
int i, j, k, l, m, x;
char **str;
scanf("%d\n", &N);
str = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * N);
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    str[i] = malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",str[i]);
}
printf("%d\n",N);   
for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
    printf("%s",str[j]);
    printf("\n");
}
scanf("%d",&Q);
printf("%d\n",Q);
char **qry_str;
qry_str = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * Q);
for(l = 0; l < Q; l++){
    qry_str = malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",qry_str[l]);
}   
for(m = 0; m < N; m++){
    printf("%s",qry_str[m]);
    printf("\n");
}

for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
    free(str[k]);
free(str);
for(x = 0; x < N; x++)
    free(qry_str[x]);
free(qry_str);
return 0;
}
```

I am new to programming, and I am trying to allocate memory for two 2d strings using malloc function, but when I try to input data for the second string qry_str, (null) appears on the screen, and the program exits.

My question is:

1. How do we dynamically allocate memory for 2D arrays in C multiple times?
2. Do I need to free the memory first before using it again? (Though when I try to do that it causes segmentation fault error.)
3. Is this the problem due to my compiler? (I am using gcc.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. When asking question, there was a big orange __How to Format__ box to the right of the text area. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a __[?]__ button giving formatting help. And a preview area  showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second case, you're overwriting `qry_str` inside the loop, which is not what is intended. You most probably want

```
for(l = 0; l < Q; l++){
    qry_str[l] = malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",qry_str[l]);
 }
```

That said, a few suggestion:

- You don't need four separate counters `i`, `j`, `l`, `m`. The first clause of `for` statement re-assigns the counter to 0 anyway, even if you reuse only one.
- `sizeof(char)` is gurantted to be 1 in C. Instead, you should consider writing the statements like

  ```
   qry_str[l] = malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof *qry_str));
  ```

  to make them more robust.
- Always check for the return values for `scanf()` family to ensure success.